# Issue installing NativeScript

Tags: android, macos, nativescript

I keep experiencing this issue with installing the native iOS and Android requirements.

This is the command

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://www.nativescript.org/setup/mac)"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the error, it looks like only the hardware emulator failed. 
Below are few tings to try or simply follow an alternate route with this [advanced setup guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-os-x), which I did and helped for me,

Below steps are to debug with the same command(install script) you used,

1) Run **`tns doctor`** and see if the nativescript setup is looking good. It may, as Android hardware emulator is not mandatory for Nativescript to work. Especially when you are planning to develop with a real device connected to your Mac.

2) If the above option says the deployment is not good, try rerunning the above script and **choose "N"** for the emulator. This will make sure to run any steps in the script after this installation which failed before.

3) After the above step is done, make sure you close and reopen the terminal and check for our **`ANDROID_HOME`** and **`JAVA_HOME`** environment variables are set. If its not set, set those with appropriate location, restart the terminal and try tns doctor again to see if it worked.

If these steps / advanced setup option didn't help, post **"tns doctor"** output along with any other error that you are getting.

Comment: @rabbit If it worked, please do share what worked so it helps others.